# date-fns-tz parse a datestamp as if it was in a specific timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-fns, date-fns-tz

I'm often in the position of wanting to extract the UTC time for a timezone-agnostic datestamp, in a particular timezone. I don't want to "convert" the stamp to the target timezone, I want the library to assume this datestamp is already in a target time zone, and give me the UTC time it would fall in.

Lets say my time zone is: Europe/Amsterdam

I want:
'2023-09-26 00:00:00' in America/New_York. So I want to tell the library "This date is Midnight on 9/26/23 in America/New_York. What is the correct Unix timestamp?"

Any strategy I try ends up converting that time to a different time in the target timezone. (GMT+2 to GMT-4). Because of daylight savings time, I can't add a timezone offset to the original datestamp. The offset changes throughout the year.

Does anyone have a strategy for this?

Edit. I've come up with something, but it feels crazy. There has to be a better way?

```js
const stamp = '2023-09-26 00:00:00';
// correct time, but wrong TZ
const wrongTz = dateFns.parse(stamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', new Date());
// correct time, TZ, but wrong Unix timestamp
const rightTzWrongUnix = dateFnsTz.toDate(wrongTz, { timeZone, locale });
// Actual correct UTC string datestamp in our target TZ
const stampWithTz = dateFnsTz.format(rightTzWrongUnix, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss XX', { locale, timeZone });
// Parse the UTC stamp
const finalDate = new Date(stampWithTz)
// This is correct!
console.log(getUnixTime(finalDate))
// >> 1695700800, Tuesday, September 26, 2023 4:00:00 GMT+0
```

The idea is that we can get date-fns-tz to output a string stamp that formats in the correct UTC time, with the proper timezone offset with/without daylight savings. The underlying date object `rightTzWrongUnix` formats properly, but internally holds the wrong Unix timestamp because thats how date-fns-tz works.

We can take that generated proper UTC stamp, read it back in with `new Date()`, which will now hold the real Unix utc timestamp.

Comment: Have you tried [*zonedTimeToUtc*](https://date-fns.org/v2.30.0/docs/Time-Zones#date-fns-tz)? e.g. `const utcDate = zonedTimeToUtc('2018-09-01 18:01:36.386', 'Europe/Berlin')`? You'll need [*date-fns-tz*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz). BTW, the statement in the date-fns docs "*a plain JS Date, which implicitly has the current system's time zone*" is misleading. ECMAScript dates are UTC, it's only the non–UTC methods (including *toString*) that return "local" values, the UTC methods all return UTC values and the time value at the heart of a *Date* is UTC.

Comment: @RobG This is much more sane! I misinterpreted that function as only the pure inverse of utcToZonedTime(). utcToZonedTime() will format strings correctly, but fundamentally alter the Unix timestamp. Applying zonedTimeToUtc() undoes that, and gets the right unix time back.

This works though! If you want to post an answer I'll mark it correct.